# Problems in starting the ThingsBoard GUI

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, virtual-machine, thingsboard

I’ve been playing with ThingsBoard PE for educational purposes (I’m a professor of Databases at L’AQuila University, Italy) for a couple of weeks.

TB runs on a Virtual machine under Ubuntu 20.4.

Unfortunately, today (after a restart of my Windows PC, without turning off the Virtual Machine) the TB GUI stopped working.

Entering TB as: tenant@thingsboard.org.
I can’t reach anymore devices, customers, rule chains, etc. previously defined by me.
On the TB GUI I read “No data available”.

Somebody can tell me what is going on?

Thanks in advance for your support.
Paolino

I tried to enter the TB GUI to add other devices and so on.